# Manipulating network traffic between containers in Docker in Docker environment without privileged mode?

Tags: python, macos, networking, docker, dockerpy

In an environment where docker containers are running inside other docker containers (by mounting the docker socket, not running as privileged), is there any way to manipulate the network to do things like:

- Introduce latency
- Drop % of packets
- Bandwidth caps

I am *only* interested in docker-to-docker traffic from containers I am starting myself with docker-py (inside the environment). I do not care about manipulating other traffic such as docker to localhost or docker to internet. In many regards it would be ideal to only manipulate docker-docker network traffic.

There are a lot of ways you can do this even within a docker container when it is run under one of the following situations:

- Privileged mode
- Passing the `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` flag runtime

A few utilities (iptables, tc, and all sorts of libraries implemented using them) allow this. But all require higher permissions than are available in my environment, since the "host" container is not started in privileged mode.

I cannot control the system configuration. I *have* to run these containers inside another container, not started in privileged mode. It would be straightforward if I could change this because I could just use any of the above listed utilities.

All the containers are attached to a network created simply by `docker network create foobar`.

My application, written in Python3.4, is using docker-py on OSX.

- Is there any way to manipulate networking for docker to docker networking characteristics to introduce latency, packet drop, etc?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is very late, but I found this why I was looking for an answer to my own question... (it does however need privileges, but thought it might be useful nonetheless)

You can introduce latency between containers using the tc command. For 
example, if the ping time is 5ms then by running the command:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 1000ms
```

the ping will now be approx. 1005 ms.

To remove the delay run the command:

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root netem
```

It's possible to simulate the complete failure of the network using the iptables command, so the following command will block all traffic to the IP address 192.168.1.202:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.202/255.255.255.255 -j DROP
```

and to unblock it again use:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s 192.168.1.202/255.255.255.255 -j DROP
```