# Docker traffic control (tc) - specified qdisc not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, traffic-simulation

I am looking for a solution to how to run `tc qdisc` command in Docker Ubuntu.

The version of Ubuntu is 20.04 LTS and I run Docker on Windows. Here's part of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
fuseki_1:
        image: leroykim/jena-fuseki:ubuntu
        container_name: fuseki_1
        depends_on: 
            - fuseki-data_1
        ports:
            - "3031:3030"
        cap_add:
            - NET_ADMIN
        command: bash -c "apt-get update && apt-get -y install iproute2"
fuseki_2:
        image: leroykim/jena-fuseki:ubuntu
        container_name: fuseki_2
        depends_on: 
            - fuseki-data_2
        ports: 
            - "3032:3030"
fuseki_3:
        image: leroykim/jena-fuseki:ubuntu
        container_name: fuseki_3
        depends_on: 
            - fuseki-data_3
        ports: 
            - "3033:3030"
```

By this setting, I want to introduce some delays, duplicates, and losses to fuseki_1 and simulate the real-world-like network during federated queries.

The commands I want to run are like this:

```sh
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 2: netem delay 100ms 5ms 25% loss 15.3% 25% duplicate 1% corrupt 0.1% reorder 5% 50%
```

The problem is that the commands keep throwing the `Error: Specified qdisc not found.` error.

I checked the several stack overflow answers and web pages. It seems they run the `tc qdisc` commands smoothly, but none of them worked for me:

- [Manipulating network traffic between containers in Docker in Docker environment without privileged mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350857/manipulating-network-traffic-between-containers-in-docker-in-docker-environment)
- [Apply NetEM WAN delay on a docker container interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899906/apply-netem-wan-delay-on-a-docker-container-interface)
- [Simulate network latency on specific port using tc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196730/simulate-network-latency-on-specific-port-using-tc)
- [Simulate high latency network using Docker containers and “tc” commands](https://medium.com/@kazushi/simulate-high-latency-network-using-docker-containerand-tc-commands-a3e503ea4307)
- [Getting advanced traffic shaping with tc and containers to work #33162](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33162)
- [Linux fedora tc qdisc gets “Error: Specified qdisc not found.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64755248/linux-fedora-tc-qdisc-gets-error-specified-qdisc-not-found) (could not install the kernel-modules-extra package)

I really appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: See: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6065

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

The Windows WSL 2 backend was the problem. I turned off the `Settings > General > Use the WSL 2 based engine` option and those commands finally worked.

For clarity, these settings are found in your Docker instance.
[image]

Comment: This isn't possible on Windows 10, its telling me that this option is required and I cannot use Docker when WSL 2 is disabled.

Comment: You also might need to install Hyper-V on Windows 10 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

Comment: that didnt fix it to me since it is on by default now .. would you know of any other cause for that